# Can I substitute grapeseed oil with peanut oil?

Tags: baking

I am making gluten free chocolate chip cookies. The recipe calls for 1/2 cup of grapeseed oil.Can I substitute peanut oil for grapeseed oil?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that would be fine. They're both very neutral, high smoke point oils, so you can consider them interchangeable in baking.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

You'll get just a touch of peanut flavor (which obviously pairs well with chocolate), and obviously watch-out for peanut allergies. Other than that, you should be good.

Comment: Actually the typical grocery stored refined peanut oil shouldn't smell of peanuts at all and should be allergy free.

http://www.peanut-institute.org/eating-well/allergy/peanut-oil-no-allergens.asp

However there are cold pressed oils that will contain trace amounts of peanuts.  So in the end be careful with your oil source or be extra safe and stick with grapeseed oil.